# Edit Permission level is Not editable

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, edit

I want to give the user the permission to add and view only in my subsite,
I went to permission levels 
Clicked on contribute 
but the  "Edit Permission Level" page is read only ,  i cant make any changes

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a custom permission level and see if it works.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/how-to-create-and-edit-permission-levels